# Spring boot rest api csv download don't set file name with extension

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing a REST API for CSV download using OpenCSV library. I am setting `Content-Disposition` for set download with file name. Currently, file downloaded but filename is not set or not any extension set. It downloaded like named `download` without extension but data is fine when I open it.

Here in controller I set `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` for response.

```
  @GetMapping("/download")
  public void download(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; file=customers.csv");
    service.download(response.getWriter());
  }
```

Here I write csv data in response writer in service.

```
  public void download(PrintWriter writer) {
    List<Resource> resources = this.getData();
    try (
      CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
    ){
      csvWriter.writeNext(this.getCsvHeader());
      for (Resource resource : resources) {
        csvWriter.writeNext(getCsvData(resource));
      }
    }catch (IOException e) {
      log.info("Writing CSV error {}",e.toString());
      throw new FailedException();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content-Disposition must use the attribute "filename"

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=customers.csv");
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks Simon Martineli it's works for me when i changed my code from "attachment; file=customers.csv" to "attachment; filename=customers.csv"